# Peformance issue for delegates

Tags: c#

```
public void printMessage(string message)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(new WriteLineHandler(printMessage), new object[] { message });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (message.Length > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("G"));
                sb.Append(": ");
                sb.Append(message);
                sb.Append("\n");
                sb.Append(richTextBox.Text);
                richTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

`this.Invoke(new WriteLineHandler(printMessage), new object[] { message });` this line takes much time to execute. Can anybody help me out to increase performance.

Comment: How much time is it? Long compared to your expectations or some other code?

Comment: I have a API which executes 10000 times and it took 2 hours time. If I remove this line this.Invoke(new WriteLineHandler(printMessage), new object[] { message }); it is executed in just 11 minutes. So there is lot of change but I don't understand how to minimize that code. Please help me out

Comment: What **is** your `Invoke` method? Can you call the method directly, `printMessage(message);`? Maybe your real problem is an unintended infinite recursion?

Comment: Actually I have two threads to execute. both threads executes simultaneously so I want to print messages in current thread.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen `Invoke` is needed to make sure that UI elements are updated from the UI thread.

Comment: So `Invoke` is [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx), I figure.

Comment: Invoking 10k times to the UI thread will not take (2h minus 11m). It will be done in seconds, probably sub-second. You are misinterpreting something. Either you're calling a lot more often, or something else is taking time. Profile to find out.

Comment: @usr Does the `Invoke` call throw an exception?

Answer (score 2):

`this.Invoke` here isn't just delegate invocation: it is sending a message to the UI thread via the message loop. That has overhead, so: try to batch up work to do - so you call it less often, but with more "stuff" in each.

There is also some overhead here with the delegate type - only a few are checked explicitly for fast/typed invoke - `MethodInvoker` is one, iirc, but that is parameterless. You can use a closure to spoof this, though:

```
MethodInvoker method = () => { … };
this.Invoke(method, null);
```

(note `EventHandler` is also special-cased; all other delegate types will use `DynamicInvoke`, which is much slower - but again : the main overhead here is the UI message loop)

Comment: @user2862430 the issue isn't "how to do it" - it is "how ***often*** to do it". 100,000 separate calls each with one value is significantly more expensive than 1000 calls, each with 100 values. The *how* is `Control.Invoke`, as per the code in the question (but perhaps using `MethodInvoker` to help a bit)

Comment: its working fine...but there is no improvement in performance

Comment: MethodInvoker method = () => { … };
this.Invoke(method, null); This line is working fine.. I mean its executing perfectly...but the question is, Is there anything else to replace this.Invoke

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

You create two objects every time. You could try to keep one or both of them. The array of object for example is an obvious contender. Just declare a static one in the method, then replace/set the first element to the new value of message when invoking.

Same approach might be used for the WriteLineHandler instance.

EDIT2:
Sorry, screwed up the example first time around.

EDIT:

As has been mentioned by others, this is not likely to be your overhead. Still, there's no need to pay for creating the array every time.

Example:

```
try {
    static object[] messageAsArray = { "dummy" };
    messageAsArray[0] = message;
    this.Invoke(new WriteLineHandler(printMessage), messageAsArray);
}
    catch (Exception)
{
            }
```

Comment: can we use static keyword for delegates

Comment: Fixed the example :) Sorry, was a little late when I put it in.